# Gradle wrapper authenticated download credentials not being picked up from environment

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, gradlew

Using gradle wrapper and specifying an internal repository URL to download the zip distribution - I followed the instructions from here: https://docs.gradle.org/5.2.1/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#sec:authenticated_download

The `https\://<username>:<password>@...` in the `distributionUrl` works fine, but it's sub-optimal - we don't want credentials checked in source control. I tried:

```
systemProp.gradle.wrapperUser=<username>
systemProp.gradle.wrapperPassword=<password>
```

and confirmed that the properties are being set; however, they seem to be completely ignored. I keep getting a 401 unauthorized error when trying to access our internal repository. I tried all possibile combinations: `systemProp.gradle.wrapperUser=username`, `gradle.wrapperUser=username` and `wrapperUser=username`, nothing seems to work.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Update: it works in Unix, but with IntelliJ, it seems to be ignoring the settings.

Comment: Issue should be already fixed in 2019 version: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-176428. What version do you use? What "gradle.properties" did you edit (file location)?

Comment: 2019.1.4, trying to set `-Dgradle.wrapperUser` and `-Dgradle.wrapperPassword` directly in the settings => Gradle VM options dialog.

Comment: Please set these options in IntelliJ custom vm options via: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out the issue was not with Gradle, but with IntelliJ, which seems to be overriding or completely ignoring the properties above. From a Unix shell script, everything works as advertised.